# Print Preview Web Part SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, data-view-web-part, migration

I've had a customer upgrade their SharePoint 2007 farm to 2010 about 2 months ago and have been fixing up some post upgrade issues that they didn't know how to fix. My attention has been drawn to some kind of print preview display of a list view. The view was just throwing an error with a correlation ID that didn't shed much light on what was going on. THey have provided me with a screen shot of what it actually used to look like and was wondering if anyone knows of a web part or perhaps some custom page code that will do what it used to, have attached the screen shots below
2007 list view
[image: 2007 list view]

2010 sharepoint native list view
[image: 2010 sharepoint native list view]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the numbers in the upper screenshot are the year levels, this could possibly be a data view web part filtered on a day and grouped by the year level. The upper screenshot does not seem to be an exact representation, though, since not all events are represented, or the list view does not show all the columns that go into the business logic for presenting the DVWP.

If you still have access to the old 2007 site, it would be worth looking at the webpart there. If it's a DVWP it should be easy to tweak.

Comment: worth a shot teylyn - i will look into it